# How to seperate characters in a string from a textfile, Python 3

Tags: python, string, dictionary, text-files, python-3.2

I need help with a thing, I am supposed to convert a textfile into a dictionary. The problem is that the textfile is just a line with multiply characters that I want to seperate.

this is the textfile:

```
A2.-B4-...C4-.-.D3-..E1.F4..-.G3--.H4....I2..J4.---
K3-.-L4.-..M2--N2-.O3---P4.--.Q4--.-R3.-.S3...T1-
U3..-V4...-W3.--X4-..-Y4-.--Z4--..Å5.--.-Ä4.-.-
Ö4---.15.----25..---35...--45....-55.....65-....
75--...85---..95----.05-----.6.-.-.-,6--..--?6..--..!5..--.
```

there is no whitespaces in the line! I want the file in a dictionary in this format:

```
'A': '.-'
'B': '-...'
```

and so on...

I figured that I could check the file for digits. If I come across one, I want to check if it has a number after it.
    'A2.-15.----'

if it doesn't have a number after: 
Then I want to store the character infront of the number as 'key' and the I want to store the same amount of characters after the digit as the number itself as 'value'.
    'A' = '.-'

if it has:
I want to store the first number as 'Value' and then store the same amount of characters as the next number(the characthers after the number)

'1': '.----'

The problem is that the whole line an element(and the only one) in the list. So I can't use index to move in the string. 
Here is my code so far:

```
file = open('morse.d.txt')
s = file.read()
l = s.split()
element = l[0]

for char in element:
    if char.isdigit():
        #Check the character after
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use regexes for this job:

```
In [1]: import re

In [2]: s="""
   ...: A2.-B4-...C4-.-.D3-..E1.F4..-.G3--.H4....I2..J4.---
   ...: K3-.-L4.-..M2--N2-.O3---P4.--.Q4--.-R3.-.S3...T1-
   ...: U3..-V4...-W3.--X4-..-Y4-.--Z4--..Å5.--.-Ä4.-.-
   ...: Ö4---.15.----25..---35...--45....-55.....65-....
   ...: 75--...85---..95----.05-----.6.-.-.-,6--..--?6..--..!5..--."""

In [3]: re.findall("([^\.-]+)([\.-]+)", s)
Out[3]: 
[('A2', '.-'),
 ('B4', '-...'),
 ('C4', '-.-.'),
 ('D3', '-..'),
...
 ('6', '.-.-.-'),
 (',6', '--..--'),
 ('?6', '..--..'),
 ('!5', '..--.')]
```

And just past that result to `dict` to get a dictionary.

Comment: This actually won't quite work.  Because you're not using the number of characters, just gobbling `.` and `-`, when `.` or `,` is being *defined* you get yourself into trouble because it's assigned to the previous key.  Look at why you have a `'6'` key, for example.